# Adding WCF Service Reference To Java Application

Tags: c#, java, .net, wcf, web-services

How can I add WCF Service Reference to my Java Console Application ? I want to use this method for prove the interoperability of my wcf Service.

---

I'm newbiee to java and I don't know what do I import to java.I have service and service.wsdl but I haven't found anywhere what will I type to import my Service reference in java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your WCF service able to return a wsdl and consume that on the Java application side.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point about web services is that they are interoperable - how do you think any application communicates with a web service? Answer: your service provides a WDSL document (Web Services Description Language) and your Java console app communicates with it, according to the WDSL, via SOAP messaging.

Comment: incompatibility of SOAP versions of java&c# use there will be a problem with communcationg wcf to java service.I know the SOAP messaging and WSDL document and what they are for.I need only Java codes for integrating Wcf service to java...There is only problem which I'm coping with.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [wscompile](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/jaxrpc/jaxrpc-tools.html) - if you have your mex endpoint enabled, wscompile should be able to generate stubs for you based on the wsdl