# How to "Add Service Reference" for a WCF service in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, wcf

I want to consume a WCF service with DataContracts from my Android app, and I'm using Eclipse as my IDE.

In .NET when I add a service reference I automatically get metadata and automatically-generated code for calling that service.

Is there a way to do so in Java/Android/Eclipse? I wouldn't want to re-code all the data contracts, nor do I want to have to manually update my code if the service contract changes.  (In .NET it's just a case of clicking "Update service reference").

How is this done in the Java world?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding WCF Service Reference To Java Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869366/adding-wcf-service-reference-to-java-application)

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the below steps to add a web reference for eclipse:

1. Select a file container in eclipse(folder) --> Right click and  select Import
2. Now from the options in the dialog select Import Web Reference and click Next
3. Enter some general settings related to the web service to import and click Next
4. Click Next again as we dont need to set anything in the advance settings dialog
5. Now you are done and all the generated files are available to use

Please refer this [link](http://wsdl2javawizard.sourceforge.net/) for more information along with screenshots